LinkedIn Sharing certificate android App issue
Recently, I have noticed that when users click on the "Add to Profile" button for certificates, the LinkedIn app opens as expected. However, upon attempting to save the certificate, users encounter an error message stating "something went wrong." This issue is specific to the LinkedIn Android app and is not reproducible on iPhones or desktop devices.
To provide more context, I have included the PHP code snippet used to generate the certificate sharing URL:
https://www.linkedin.com/profile/add?startTask=CERTIFICATION_NAME&name=&organizationName=ScyllaDB&issueYear=&issueMonth=&certUrl=
Additionally, I have attempted to troubleshoot the issue by replacing the certificate sharing URL with test data, but unfortunately, the error persists. Here is an example of the test URL used:
https://www.linkedin.com/profile/add?startTask=CERTIFICATION_NAME&name=Test%20Certificate&organizationId=1337&issueYear=2018&issueMonth=2&expirationYear=2020&expirationMonth=5&certUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flearn%2Fcertifications%2Fd365-functional-consultant-sales&certId=1234
Image
I have attempted to troubleshoot the issue by replacing the certificate sharing URL with test data, but unfortunately, the error persists. Here is an example of the test URL used:
https://www.linkedin.com/profile/add?startTask=CERTIFICATION_NAME&name=Test Certificate&organizationId=1337&issueYear=2018&issueMonth=2&expirationYear=2020&expirationMonth=5&certUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flearn%2Fcertifications%2Fd365-functional-consultant-sales&certId=1234

Have you resolved this issue? If not, what steps did you take to bypass this feature? I am stuck with the same issue.
